# Sentence inversion for questions

Tags: grammaire, négation, questions

I have trouble understanding how to invert the sentences with these:

(n'est-ce pas)
**N'est-ce j'aime pas voyager?** 
Oui, j'aime voyager.

(est-ce que)
**Est-ce que vous sommes étudiants?** 
Oui, nous sommes étudiants.

(d'accord)
**Tu aimes manger au resto U, d'accord?** 
Mais non! Je n'aime pas manger au resto U.

However, I remember this one was correct:
(est-ce que)
**Est-ce que les cours commencent demain?** 
Non, les cours ne commencent pas demain.

Comment: What do you mean by inverting sentences? From some of the examples you give it might mean asking a question with "*est-ce que*" ? But then you have one with "*d'accord*"...  Besides your use of personal pronouns is confusing. Sentence 1: "*je*" used in question **and** answer (not the sort of question one would ask oneself) Sentence 2:  "*nous sommes*" or "*vous êtes*" but you can't mix. Sentence 1 is the most difficult to understand, could be "*Est-ce que tu n'aimes pas voyager* ?"

Comment: @Laure _"Est-ce que tu n'aimes pas voyager ?"_ the answer would then be _"Si, j'aime voyager._" of course :)

Comment: @oerkelens: I agree, and the same goes with the answer he gives to the second question. But this doesn't help understanding what OP's after.

Answer (score 6):

Tell me if I'm wrong, but I think you want to know how to invert subject/verb in questions while using "Est-ce que" or "n'est-ce pas" to formulate the question.

If so, please note the following:

1) You need to invert subject and verb if you ask the question without those expressions, e.g.:

> Aimes-tu voyager ? Oui, j'aime voyager.

2) If you decide to use "Est-ce que" to create your question, then there is NO inversion, e.g.:

> Est-ce que tu aimes voyager ? Oui, j'aime voyager.

Note: You add "Est-ce que" at the beginning of the afirmative sentence, which makes it interrogative.

3) Almost the same goes for "N'est-ce pas", except you add it at the end of the sentence, e.g.:

> Tu aimes voyager, n'est-ce pas ? Oui, j'aime voyager.

Note: In that case, you ask the question but you have an idea of the answer. You're asking for a confirmation.

For "D'accord", I don't think it's really used. It seems more like an English expression literally translated into French.

Comment: « d'accord » est quelque fois employé en langage familier pour imposer un choix ou exiger une action : Un parent à son enfant : « Tu marches sur le trottoir !! D'accord ? » sous-entendu : sinon je vais me fâcher) » ; c'est une expression impérative : il n'y a pas de réponse négative possible, sinon c'est la rébellion. La tournure (familière)  « Tu manges au resto U, d'accord ? » sous entend : « on y va [tout de suite] ensemble » ; sinon, il ne faut pas utiliser cette tournure, à la limite de la correction, car on voudrait alors imposer son point de vue.

Comment: Le site étant ouvert à ceux qui se passionnent pour la langue française, il est tout à fait possible de répondre en français à une question formulée en anglais.

Comment: @cl-r Si on veut s'assurer d'être compris par contre, il vaut mieux répondre dans la langue d'interrogation. Ce ne sont pas tous les utilisateurs qui parlent les deux langues, en particulier ceux qui commencent à apprendre le français, et répondre en français à leur niveau ne les aide pas du tout. Il y a ensuite toutes les autres personnes qui trouvent la question par Google, pensent que la réponse sera dans la même langue et trouvent notre site inutile. Il est donc vraiment préférable de répondre dans la même langue. La fonction d'édition existe pour corriger les erreurs au besoin.

Comment: Mais je croyais qu'on ne utilise plus « n'est-ce pas » ?

Comment: Dans une phrase telle que "Tu aimes voyager, n'est-ce pas ?", c'est très utilisable. Ça implique seulement qu'on demande une confirmation. On se doute que la personne aime voyager, et on lui demande de confirmer.

Answer (score 0):

Vous pouvez aussi dire:

> N'est-ce pas que tu aimes voyager?
>
> Est-ce que vous êtes étudiants?
>
> D'accord que tu aimes manger au resto U?

I'm answering assuming that you can add one or two words as long as they help you use the suggested ones. e.g. That's why I added the "que" in the last line.