# Is it correct to repeat the inversion of subject and verb in a question?

Tags: grammaire, questions, inversion

In written form, is it correct to repeat the inversion in a question?
For example: "Pensez-vous......, auriez-vous... ?"

The sentence was: "Pensez-vous que jusqu'au 30 août auriez-vous le temps...?"

Comment: What do you mean with "repeat the inversion in a question". There's no repetition in *Pensez-vous ?...* or *Auriez-vous?...*? And can you look as the answers to these to see if you can find an answer to your question? [Inversions in questions](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/24985/358)   [Sentence inversion for questions](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/8845/358).

Comment: It's the same sentence. It starts by "Pensez-vous" and in the middle there's "auriez-vous". These forms are separated by a comma, in the same sentence. Could you tell me, please, if it's correct?

Comment: It's probably better if you can be more explicit in your question. Join two sentences with *et* is always possible, for example : *Peux-tu manger et peux-tu m'écouter en même temps ?* Having a comma might depend on what you want to say. I just wonder why you want a comma and not a period.

Comment: @None Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think I have answered your question, I'm sure there are plenty of possibilities according to what verbs you use, what follows, etc.

Comment: But it isn't strictly incorrect from a grammatical point of view to use the inversion more than once, right?

Comment: @MichelT Using the inversion twice would put the subject-verb back in their original order...

Comment: @jlliagre So it would be incorrect? User None didn't mention that in his answer

Comment: Sorry, I should probably have added a smiley to my previous comment. I was just stating that *Vous pensez* inverted gives *Pensez-vous*, but inverted again gives back *Vous pensez*... There is no such thing as a "double inversion". Double negation for example exists in English : "I don't want no cake" but two successive negative verbal forms ("I don't want cake, I don't want a drink") do not make a double negation. That's the same with inversions. Two successive inversions are not a double inversion.

Comment: LOL now I get it, sorry! Thanks a lot!

Comment: So your question is basically: Is it grammatical to say "Do you want some cake, do you want a drink?" The issue is quite similar in French. The comma is odd.

Comment: @jlliagre The sentence was: "Pensez-vous que jusqu'au 30 aôut auriez-vous le temps...?" I didn't know if it was gramatically correct. Could you give me your two cents?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now! You should update your question with it. The answer is: no, that's not grammatical. That should be: *Pensez-vous que d'ici au 30 août, vous auriez le temps... ?*

Comment: Thanks... do you think it's a very bad mistake? The message was already sent like that

Comment: That depends on how you define *very bad*. If that was your application letter for the Académie française, it's dead :-) If the main goal was to be understood, I have no doubt that's the case.

Comment: In English: "Do you think you'll have time to do it?" vs "Do you think will you have time to do it?"

Comment: On se trompe et on s'enfarge dans sa propre phrase et la deuxième question est comme une modification de la première, on voulait possiblement dire _pensez-vous avoir le temps de... faire qqc... jusqu'au 30_. Ou on s'est planté avec l'indication de temps, on voulait dire d'_ici le 30_, comme _trouver un moment d'ici le 30_. Parfois j'entends des gens dire des trucs pareils. On essaye de se rattraper mais c'est mal ficelé.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we write two full sentences we would usually have a question mark after each question.

- *Pourriez-vous mettre le chien dans le jardin ? Auriez-vous l’obligeance de refermer la porte derrière vous.*

The way to escape that would be to join the two sentences with *et*, not a comma.

- *Pourriez-vous mettre le chien dans le jardin et auriez-vous l’obligeance de fermer la porte derrière vous ?*

It is grammatical but sounds rather awkward. Personally I would rather write:

- *Pourriez-vous mettre le chien dans le jardin et avoir l'obligeance de fermer la porte derrière vous ?*

With a different sentence we could have:

- *As-tu déjà pris le train et es-tu déjà allé en France ?*

And you would have *et* or two question marks, not a comma.

---

Now that the question [has been edited](https://french.stackexchange.com/revisions/47241/1) the answer above is no longer suited.

<s>*Pensez-vous que jusqu'au 30 août auriez-vous le temps...?"*</s> is not correct at all.
Even if eventually you want to know if the person has time, the question you want to ask is on *penser*, not *avoir le temps*. *Avoir le temps* is part of the information asked for but it is not part of the grammatical question, grammatically that part of the sentence is a subordinate clause that depends on the main clause that is *pensez-vous.*.

- *Pensez-vous que jusqu'au 30 aout vous auriez le temps (de...) ?*

You could also write:

- *Pensez avoir le temps (de...) d'ici le 30 août ?*